# Не работает SQL запрос UPDATE в QT на C++

Tags: c++, sql, qt

мой пример

```
 query.prepare("UPDATE TableExample SET Like = " + true + " WHERE id = "+id);
```

не компилируется и пишет `invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [13]' to binary 'operator '`

Советовали решать такую проблему путем `=:` или `=@`, но у меня это не работает (ничего не меняется в БД и пишет `error update   TableExample "No query Unable to fetch row"` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ не умеет складывать две сишные строки.

Поэтому, сделайте где то так

```
QString q = "UPDATE TableExample SET Like = ";
q += true; // это странная конструкция, работать не будет
q += "true"; // может так? компилироваться будет, но смысла мало
q +=  " WHERE id = "+QString::number(id);
query.prepare(q);
```

или так

```
query.prepare(QString("UPDATE TableExample SET Like = %1 WHERE id = %2").arg(true).arg(id));
```

Но с true лучше разобраться.

А теперь самый правильный способ

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("UPDATE TableExample SET Like = :text WHERE id = :id");
query.bindValue(":id", id);
query.bindValue(":text", "true");
query.exec();
```

Comment: получается в данном случае true- это string?

Comment: я поставил строку. Но я честно не знаю структуры таблицы. И явно написал, что выглядит странно. Показывайте структуру таблицы и что там должно быть, попробуем найти хороший вариант

Comment: там bool, который возвращается после работы функции (isChecked). Все работает правильно, я исправила. Подскажите, а если у меня для разных колонок происходит Update, то QSqlQuery query создавать разные? За что оно вообще отвечает?

Comment: QSqlQuery  в себе содержит Ваш запрос и связанные с ним штуки

Answer (score 0):

Правильное использование prepare. рекомендуется запросы подготавливать именно так, поскольку во-первых даст правильное преобразование типов на основе драйвера СУБД (тот же формат времени/даты) и защитит от sql инъекций (в отличие от простого конструирования QString)

```
query.prepare("UPDATE TableExample SET Like = :Like WHERE id = :id");
query.bindValue(":Like",true);
query.bindValue(":id",id);
query.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо так делать - сделайте так:

```
QString queryStr = " UPDATE TableExample SET  Like =:Like WHERE id =:Id";
query.prepare(queryStr);

bool Like =true;
//Аналогиично с Id    Id=...

query.bindValue(":Like ",Like );
query.bindValue(":Id",Id);

if( !query.exec() )
{
    QSqlError err = query.lastError();
    // ... mLogger.AddMessage(err.text());
    // ....
}
```